# Are persistent variable values after the kernel is stopped possible?

Tags: persistence

Is there a way to make values of variables persistent even after the kernel is stopped?

Example, if I were to set up a list for which I append new list items (such as a check ledger, as a basic example).  If I stop the kernel, the value of the variable is lost. I can import/export to .csv, .txt, or .xlsx but that kind of defeats the point.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: this sounds like a perfect application for a database, see [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/tutorial/Introduction.html)

Comment: @Jens I use databases at work and they work pretty great. But I'm not sure there are good solutions for Mac (what I use at home) in this regard. And that would be almost the same as the import/export of tabular data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/saving-data-inside-a-notebook-so-that-i-dont-have-to-run-it-again/5966#5966) with interesting answers, where [I suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5966/109) storing in the notebook's tagging rules. Just use something like this as a variable `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "myvars", "x"}]` and it will be stored in the notebook, so it survives kernel crashes. 
If it's something big however, I would probably use `DumpSave` before quitting the kernel, and load it in an initialization cell. It's not nice to have 800MB notebooks around

Comment: I like the tagging method with or without the use of Compress[], but I think with the large amount of data, DumpSave/Get-ing the variable is probably the best solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A  very fine solution is given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291299/615464) by WReach on Stackoverflow/Mathematica. He provides an approach with simple file-backed storage during operations. An alternative using SQL is given as well.

Answer (score 4):

Some fancy ways have already been posted, but I'd like to mention the simple ones.

#### Per Notebook

Use an Initialization Cell (`Cell > Cell Properties > Initialization Cell`) for code that should be evaluated any time you first evaluate code in the Notebook in each session.

#### Globally

Use the `Kernel\init.m` file (`FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`) for code that is run every time the kernel is started.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap (the relevant part of) your code in `DynamicModule`. The documentation says "Symbols specified in a `DynamicModule` will by default have their values maintained even across Mathematica sessions."

Comment: Welcome :). The difficulty with this solution is that you can only wrap a single cell in `DynamicModule` so unless you use it in a creative dynamic way, there's not much you can do with this, I think.

Comment: You could use this sort of construct: <code>DynamicModule[{a=0},Row[{Button["+",a+=1],Button["-",a-=1],Dynamic[a]}]]</code>

Comment: It would be nice to add to your answer a use case of your idea to save and load with a couple of buttons some saved variable. For example, `SetAttributes[dataSaver, HoldFirst];
dataSaver[sym_] := 
 DynamicModule[{bck = 0}, 
  Row[{Button["Save " <> ToString@Unevaluated@sym <> " ownvalues", 
     bck = sym], 
    Button["Load " <> ToString@Unevaluated@sym <> " ownvalues", 
     sym = bck]}],
  Initialization :> (sym = bck)]`

Comment: I agree with your suggestion about giving more comprehensive answers. As you can see in my comment above, I fleshed things out a bit, but it didn't display nicely (I thought I had deleted the comment!). Any ideas why the code.../code section didn't work as I had intended?

Comment: I use backticks to write code. If you want to know more, when you're writing a comment there's a help link that leads you to some info, and then a Learn more link that leads you to loads more