# How to change the appearance of a Cell GroupOpener?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I would like to change the Cell GroupOpener appearance.

[image: Cell GroupOpener]

In the present Mathematica design it is too small and can be missed by a reader unfamiliar with Mma. I know, how to change its color through the OptionInspector.

Now, how can I put there something instead of the check-mark that is there at present? For example, a gray triangle that has been there previously, of something more complex, some graphics of my own design

**Edit**: To answer the question of Silva below:
This is how the Cell GroupOpener looks like at my machine operating on Windows XP, Mma 9.0.1.

[image]

Now on my other machine with Windows 7 and same Mma version the GroupOpener looks like a tiny check-mark. It is hardly visible and it is more difficult to operate (i.e. to open and close). For example, visually it is difficult to distinguish the closed from the open one. I am sorry, being presently at the machine with the XP I cannot provide an image for the GroupOpener at Win7.

Now, it is not too bad, as long as it concerns myself, this or that GroupOpener presentation is it. However, I am creating documents to give away, and need that inexperienced people would easily identify the GroupOpener and easily operate with it. So I would like to be able to control its appearance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but you should look at Opener > Options > Appearance in the Documentation Center where this is discussed.

Comment: Is this question about changing a notebook's style or is it about controlling the appearance of an `Opener` control in code?

Comment: @m_goldberg I guess OP is asking about the [Cell GroupOpeners](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VJoPt.png).

Comment: @Alexei I think a screenshot would help to clarify your question. And I think the GroupOpener is disabled by default, so it might be helpful to explain what is this *GroupOpener* and how to enable them. Also, I can see the Cell GroupOpeners are "check-mark" under Windows, but are they the same under Mac / Linux? In other words, it might be helpful to clarify if your question is OS related.

Comment: @Sylvia. On OS X a group opener is a right facing triangle. I think it is stored in /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/Resources/RightArrow.icns, and I think one would have to change that icon file to change the appearance of a group opener. However, I am too timid to try the experiment on my system, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @m_goldberg I looked around the system files on my Windows, but unfortunately I am unable to find a similar file here :( I think maybe we can construct a homemade opener with `Dynamic` things.

Comment: @m_goldberg I would first of all be able to define the GroupOpener within the StyleSheet. I would be also interested to able to do that without the StyleSheet, say, just through the OptionInspector. As Silvia noted I am asking about Cell GroupOpeners

Comment: I guess it's doable by using `Dynamic` in `CellDingbat` or similar options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellGroupData.html), `CellGroupData` supports `Dynamic`-object as its status. So with the help of `CellGrouping -> Manual`, we can design our own "CellGroup opener". It can be a `Button` or `EventHandler` placed in `CellDingbat`, `CellFrameLabels`, etc. Here is a simple demostration (tested in Mathematica 9.0.1 and 10.0 pre-release on Windows 8.1):

[image: animation demo for self-made CellGroup opener]

```
openerIconOpen = 
  GraphicsBox[{RGBColor[0.26, 0.59, 0.26], 
    PolygonBox[{{0, -0.25`}, {-0.3`, 0.25`}, {0.3`, 0.25`}, {0, -0.25`}}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 15, PlotRange -> All];

openerIconClosed = 
  GraphicsBox[{RGBColor[0.8, 0.16, 0.17], 
    PolygonBox[{{0.5, 0}, {0, -0.3}, {0, 0.3}, {0.5, 0}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 15, PlotRange -> All];

cellopenflag$1 = True;
cellopenflag$2 = False;

Clear[openerBoxFunc]
openerBoxFunc[flag_] := TagBox[
                               DynamicBox[If[flag, $CellContext`openerIconOpen, $CellContext`openerIconClosed]],
                               EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" :> (flag = ! flag)}]
                              ]

cellBodys = {
             "This is a Text Cell.",
             BoxData[RowBox[{"Another Text Cell with GridBox: ", GridBox[{{"a", "b", "c"}}, GridBoxDividers -> {"Rows" -> {{True}}, "Columns" -> {{True}}}]}]],
             BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "-", "2"}]],
             BoxData[RowBox[{"-", "1"}]],
             BoxData[DynamicBox[GridBox[{{"cellopenflag$1", "cellopenflag$2"}, {cellopenflag$1, cellopenflag$2}}, GridBoxDividers -> {"Rows" -> {{True}}, "Columns" -> {{True}}}]]]
            };

Notebook[{
   (* Start of group 1: *)
   Cell[CellGroupData[{
      (* Cell 1: *)
      Cell[cellBodys[[1]], "Text",
           CellDingbat -> openerBoxFunc[$CellContext`cellopenflag$1]
          ],
      (* Cell 2: *)
      Cell[cellBodys[[2]], "Text"],
      (* Start of group 2: *)
      Cell[CellGroupData[{
         (* Cell 3: *)
         Cell[cellBodys[[3]], "Input",
              CellDingbat -> openerBoxFunc[$CellContext`cellopenflag$2]
             ],
         (* Cell 4: *)
         Cell[cellBodys[[4]], "Output"]
         },
         Dynamic[$CellContext`cellopenflag$2]
        ]](* <- End of group 2. *)
      },
      Dynamic[$CellContext`cellopenflag$1]
     ]](* <- End of group 1. *),
   (* Cell 5: *)
   Cell[cellBodys[[5]], "Text"]
   }(* <- End of Notebook body. *),
  CellGrouping -> Manual,
  ShowGroupOpener -> False
  ] // NotebookPut
```

Comment: This is a neat implementation.  Is it possible to design a template with this type of functionality?  In my initial attempts, editing a stylesheet complains when trying to add the option `CellDingbat -> openerBoxFunc[...]`

Comment: @bobthechemist Thanks! Maybe we can define the `openerBoxFunc` [in the stylesheet](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7738/17).

Comment: @bobthechemist After another thought, I think it might be better to post process a completed Notebook than to integrate the function in stylesheet...

Comment: @Silvia Great. Is it possible to make analogous thing by hand, rather thjan programmatically. For example, would it be possible to open the background cell code (Sift+Ctrl+E) and edit it such that this functionality would be included?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thanks for accepting! Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to access `CellGroupData[...]` by the Shift+Ctrl+E method. Maybe we'll have to deal with it at the Notebook expression level. (That is why I think stylesheet approach will be very hard if not impossible.)

Comment: Nice one. @AlexeiBoulbitch Perhaps a palette would be a simpler compromise than trying to do magic with a stylesheet, and would allow you to turn it on and off on the selected cellgroup

Comment: @Rojo The truth is I don't really know about how to make magic stylesheets :P I can't see how to set a style (if the status can be called as a "style") for `Cell[CellGroupData[ contents , status ]]`.

Comment: @Silvia hehe, a NotebookDynamicExpression that continuously reparses the whole notebook :D. Speaking seriously, I also doubt it is possible to set the group opener variable by style. Perhaps there's some undocumented event that triggers on each new cell group? Who knows

Comment: Or a style with a CellDynamicExpression that runs once, and replaces itself with another style and in the process parses possible cellgroups? All hacks, nothing nice

Comment: @Silvia This comment is just to report that I tried to copy-paste the cells with the group opener from your method to another notebook. Copy-pasting is possible, but makes several problems reported below. Altogether they make impossible the use of such a method for large documents. The problems are the following: 1) The group opener in a new document works always together with the initial one. 2) If the group opener is pasted into several places of a new document, all these group openers work synchronously. 3) The copied group openers only show up after the initial code is evaluated.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The synchronous working is because they share the same `cellopenflag$xxx` status variables, so we'll need to (programmly) generate unique status variables for each `CellGroupData`. About issue 3, maybe we can put the initial code in the *init.m* file of the mma kernel, or as a `NotebookDynamicExpression` for the notebooks. Also you can consider the [`TaggingRules` method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6947/17) for storing the status.

Answer (score 1):

in the absence of a suitable answer to change the appearance of the cell opener and if the cell does not require user edits, you can set WholeCellGroupOpener to True (Format menu - Option Inspector under Cell Options (ensure you have the cell selected)) or by using the Classroom Assistant palette in the Content drop down menu in the Writing and Formatting section and avoid using the cell opener all together.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is not what I am asking about. In the case I already have put ShowCellOpener->True, I would like to be able to control, how the Group Opener looks like. May I, say, use an arrow instead of the triangle, or a check mark? Or may I fix it to be a triangle both at Windows XP and Windows 7. May I change its color? Red instead of gray? That are the questions.