# Change GroupOpener in OptionsInspector or Stylesheet?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

The accepted answer in [How to change the appearance of a Cell GroupOpener?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46082/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-a-cell-groupopener) gives programmatic methods for changing the shape, color, or other appearance of a cell `GroupOpener`.

I don't see any way to use the Option Inspector to change what dingbat or other symbol is used for the opener. Is there some way to do it by modifying the stylesheet?

Comment: There's ``GroupOpenerColor``, but it has no real effect. ``GroupOpenerInsideFrame`` does have an effect, but it's not what you want I think. There's also this: ``VirtualGroupData`` but I don't know what it does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. If it were possible, then the new v11.1 documentation style would use it instead of re-implementing the opener the same way as in the answer you linked to.