# How can I restore Default stylesheet's new type of group openers?

Tags: front-end, cells, customization, stylesheet, document-creation

With the Default stylesheet (in Mathematica 13.1 and several versions earlier), the new kind of group opener for sections, subsections, etc., appears as in this screenshot:

[image: group openers by default]

When I apply a certain stylesheet to the notebook, it loses those group openers. (The stylesheet is a variant of David Park's Presentations stylesheet.)

What option(s) do I set, and with what value(s), in the Option Inspector to restore those default group openers?

Comment: I think I have it: open the stylesheet, select Section style, open Option Inspector, and change Cell Options > Display Options > ShowGroupOpener to Inline. Ditto for Subsection, Subsubsection, etc., as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the stylesheet, select Section, open Option Inspector, and change Cell Options > Display Options > ShowGroupOpener value to Inline. Ditto for Subsection, Subsubsection, etc., as desired.

[image: Select style from stylesheet]

[image: Set Inline as ShowGroupOpener value]

Answer (score 0):

I never used David Park's Presentations stylesheet (and I know that he stopped supporting it a long time ago), but in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171305/280) answer [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1) demonstrated how to attach a GroupOpener to a `CellGroup` using `FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "cellGroupOpenerInline"]`.

Comment: Does not seem to work. If I execute this before the first Section cell, nothing happens when that cell group is closed; if I execute it before the first Subsection cell of that section, again nothing happens.