# How get this kind of group opener?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, stylesheet

Some notebooks of mine have Section (and Subsection) cells formatted like the following, so that clicking on the icon to the right of the Section's title opens the entire group of cells in that Section:

[image: Icon to open entire Section]

But I cannot reproduce this behavior in a new notebook. What is the magic setting in the Option Inspector to get this kind of icon to open groups?

With the Default stylesheet, the desired icons, inline to the right of the Section titles, automatically appear when the Section groups are closed.

However, I am already using a custom stylesheet here — a variant of David's Presentations stylesheet —  (hence the colored background). So the question amounts to asking what else I need to do to get that displayed group opener.

**Related:** [How restore Default stylesheet's new type of group openers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272106/how-restore-default-stylesheets-new-type-of-group-openers).

Unfortunately, the method I showed there in my own answer to the question no longer seems to work.

Comment: does `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> "Inline"]` give what you need?

Comment: You have to [Close the group](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/OpenAndCloseCellGroups.html).

Comment: @Domen: The group is already closed.

Comment: @kglr: No, that `SetOptions` (with the stylesheet I'm already using) leaves the openers in the form of `>` symbols to the left of the section titles (which become inverted carets when the groups are opened. Note also that I don't want all groups to have these openers, just Section (and Subsection) groups.

Comment: @murray, the openers on the left side with `^` appear when the option `ShowGroupOpener` is set to either `"InsideFrame"` or `"OutsideFrame"` (see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El6LF.png)). You should set it to `"Inline"` as proposed by @kglr. Otherwise, please include relevant screenshots and custom stylesheet so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Domen: You are correct: choosing "Inline" in the Option Inspector for Section (and Subsection) cells in the stylesheet does fix the problem.

Comment: @murray, I suggest you accept your answer in [the other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272106/how-restore-default-stylesheets-new-type-of-group-openers) so that we can close this one and mark it as a duplicate.