# How to config Mathematica to make Cell GroupOpener visible?

Tags: front-end, configuration

I am using Mathematica 12 and I am trying to set up some global preferences. What I am looking for is a way to set up globally (i.e. once and for all), for the Cells of `Chapter`, `Subchapter` styles that I create, to make the their GroupOpener visible.

Is there a way to configure it once and for all?

Comment: I do not understand what "the opening of different chapters" means.

Comment: When one sets a title, a section or a subsection (or anything else), then this subdivision of the nb has a title, i.e. it is like a chapter. I know that there is a way to configure globally, by double click in the cell on the right or next to the section, the "opening" or "closing" of that section/subsection etc.

Comment: @Szabolcs I _think_ OP is looking for a way to setup keyboard bindings for opening / closing cell subgroups. e.g. `ALT + 1` would toggle open / close of all Title style cells.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Actually, Alt+1 creates a title cell, Alt+2 a subtitle, etc. hal: I still do not understand, sorry ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry, I should have been more specific. On MacOs, `Cmd+1` creates title, etc.

Comment: Are you referring to [Cell GroupOpener](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46082/17)?

Comment: @Silvia Yes, I am referring to that. In the "Options for Global Preferences", there is no option that makes the cell on the right to have a little arrow and therefore facilitating its opening/closing. This used to be a feature in e.g. Mathematica 11.1.

Comment: Now it's clear. Please edit that into the question.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edited the question according to OP's comment.

Comment: It appears that the option is present (ShowGroupOpener), but the notebook setting does not always inherit the global setting by default. Instead, it checks whether the stylesheet has a setting. If yes, it uses that, otherwise, it inherits the global setting. The default stylesheet does happen to have this set, so it prevents the global setting from taking effect. (Sorry, I don't know how to work around with this.)

Comment: Hey, no problem and thank you! The thing is that if I choose `CellOptions`->`DisplayOptions`->`ShowGroupOpener` : `Inline`, I can open and close sections but after I evaluate a cell with multiple lines, I can't put the cursor at an arbitrary point of the expression by just clicking (in that point) with the mouse. I can only navigate with the keyboard arrows!

Comment: @hal Hi there, I don't understand the cursor part in your last comment, neither do I observed that kind of issue here. Could it be operating system related? Could you please clarify it further?

Comment: @Silvia No it's not because yesterday it  was perfectly fine. Me trying to find a solution for the above, somehow broke staff. Is there a way to wipe clean all the global configurations? Now its even worse, I can't see the cursor at all in the cell.

Comment: Without ability to reproduce it, we can hardly help. But I think that sounds like some serious issue in the FrontEnd. I would suggest you make sure your work is saved safely and then contact Wolfram's service.

Comment: I don't think so. I just selected a preference that messed things up. Is there a way to reset global preferences?

Comment: Hey, I just put the `ShowGroupOpener : None` and everything went back to normal. I don't know what is the issue or why it behaves like that. Thanks for the help.