# Storing data in the Notebook in readable form

Tags: front-end, notebooks, data

The common problem in my work is a need to import some experimental data to work with. This means that my notebook depends on some external files which makes it difficult to share it with others and inconvenient when I return to it after time.

What I wish is to have a way to store the data inside the Notebook in collapsible `CellGroup`s in order to have an ability to view the data in human-readable tabular form and to re-import the data file manually if I change it.

Generally, the data inside of the notebook should look as on the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The output `Сell`s are regenerated by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the data files change. What I need is a way to retrieve the data sets from the output cells in the section `"The data cells"`. Something like this:

```
dataSet1 = getData["Data set 1"];
dataSet2 = getData["Data set 2"];
```

where `"Data set 1"` and `"Data set 2"` are the text strings in the `Subsubsection` cells from the section `"The data cells"`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: No finished product, but I´d use a `Button` to import the data and generate an assignment cell that is output below that.

Comment: I don't understand very well. You have written "The output cells are regenerated manually when the data files change". Do you confirm the word "manually" or is it a error ?

Comment: @andre Yes, the output cells with the data will be generated manually by evaluating the above `"Input"` cells with the `Import` statements as showed on the screenshot.

Comment: @andre Probably the word "manually" is not the best choice. I just mean that the cells with `Import` statements must not be `Initialization` cells because I wish do not depend on the external files. At the same time, if the external files are changed it should be possible to regenerate the cells with the data by `Import`ing the external files. So the output cells are generated automatically by *Mathematica* but manually in the sence that they are not `Initialization` cells. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which I currently use. It isn't perfect but serves quite well for my purposes.

In the Notebook I define an auxiliary function which takes a variable where a data array is stored and prints an initialization `Cell` with two-dimensional human-readable representation of that array which will be assigned to the input variable on initialization:

```
ClearAll[printInitCell];
SetAttributes[printInitCell, HoldAll];
printInitCell[array_] := 
  CellPrint@Cell[
    BoxData[RowBox[{ToString[Unevaluated[array]], "=", 
       GridBox[Map[ToBoxes, array, {-1}], 
        GridBoxFrame -> {"Columns" -> {{True}}, "Rows" -> {{True}}}], ";"}]], "Output", 
    InitializationCell -> True, Evaluatable -> True];
```

Here is an example of use:

```
dataset1 = Prepend[RandomReal[1, {5, 3}], {"Head1", "Head2", "Head3"}];
printInitCell[dataset1]
```

[image: screenshot]

It is important that after initialization the variable `dataset1` contains two-dimensional array which is not wrapped by `Grid`:

[image: screenshot]

The only drawback of this approach is that when I need to re-generate the initialization `Cell`, I [have to remove the previous `Cell` manually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23149/280).

---

### UPDATE

With `AutoIndent -> False` and the variable placed above the data table the data `Cell`s are more readable:

```
ClearAll[printInitCell];
SetAttributes[printInitCell, HoldAll];
printInitCell[array_] := 
  CellPrint@Cell[
    BoxData[RowBox[{ToString[Unevaluated[array]], " ", "=", " ", "\n", 
       GridBox[Map[ToBoxes, array, {-1}], 
        GridBoxFrame -> {"Columns" -> {{True}}, "Rows" -> {{True}}}, 
        BaseStyle -> (FontWeight -> Plain)], ";"}]], "Output", InitializationCell -> True,
     Evaluatable -> True, AutoIndent -> False, Background -> GrayLevel[0.95], 
    FontWeight -> Bold];
```

Now

[image: screenshot]

---

### UPDATE 2

Here is *Mathematica* 8 - compatible solution which auto-overwrites previous version of the data `Cell` (if present) before printing of the new version.

At first, it checks whether the next `Cell` is a previous version by comparing the `CellTags`. If the latter is true it sets the `Evaluatable -> False` option [what turns on automatic overwriting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23149/280). Then it prints the new version and collapses the `CellGroup` hiding everything except to the newly printed initialization cell.

```
ClearAll[printInitCell];
SetAttributes[printInitCell, HoldAll];
printInitCell[var_] := With[{tag = ToString[Unevaluated[var]], nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
   SelectionMove[nb, After, EvaluationCell, AutoScroll -> False];
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
   If[CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[], CellTags] === {tag, "CellType=DataCell"}, 
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[], Evaluatable -> False]];
   CellPrint@
    Cell[BoxData[
      RowBox[{ToString[Unevaluated[var]], " ", "=", " ", "\n", 
        GridBox[Map[ToBoxes, var, {-1}], 
         GridBoxFrame -> {"Columns" -> {{True}}, "Rows" -> {{True}}}, 
         BaseStyle -> (FontWeight -> Plain)], ";"}]], "Output", 
     InitializationCell -> True, Evaluatable -> True, AutoIndent -> False, 
     Background -> GrayLevel[0.95], FontWeight -> Bold, 
     CellTags -> {tag, "CellType=DataCell"}];
   SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
   FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"]];
```

Answer (score 4):

I use buttons for this purpose. Imagine that your data is stored in a variable called `data`. Then you can do the following:

```
With[{i = Compress[data]}, 
  Button["Retrieve Data", data = Uncompress[i]; 
  Print[Style["Data has successfully been loaded into variable \"data\"",Blue,Italic,14]]]
]
```

This creates a button. When pressed, `data` is populated with your original data.

A warning: If you have a separate variable `data` already as part of your notebook, it will be overwritten.

**An alternative:**

Create initiialization cells somewhere in your notebook containing

```
data1 = <your data 1>;
data2 = <your data 2>;
```

To save space you can also do

```
data1 = Uncompress[Compress[<your data 1>]];
```

Then, highlight `Compress[<your data 1>]` and evaluate it in place (`Ctrl-Shift-Enter`)

Comment: You might also mention that the data is stored across sessions because of the way `Button` works.

Comment: @YvesKlett That's right. In fact, you can select the cell containing the button, and press Ctrl-Shift-E to see the underlying Cell code. you will see the (compressed version of) your data there. That's the reason why you need the `With[...]` construct, without it, it would not work.

Comment: @Thomas As I stated in the question, I wish to store data in readable form, as tables. I need not to compress it since the data have small size.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov you can simply print out `data` as well within the same `With`.

Comment: I know it but the goal is to *store* data in obvious and readable form, not just to display them. And at the same time the cells with the data should be generated by `Import`ing external files.

Answer (score 2):

I put in a defer because of [your question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23149/4330). Maybe you have symbols in your data and this will be useful, who knows. getData succesfully gets the data from the generated cell.

```
int = 1;
With[
  {string = "@#$kill me" <> ToString[int]}
  ,
  NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> string]]; 
  CellPrint[
   ExpressionCell[
    Defer[{{1 + 1, 2}, {1 + 1, 2}, {1 + 1, 2}} // TableForm], 
    "Output", GeneratedCell -> True, Evaluatable -> True, 
    CellTags -> string]]
  ];

getDataHeldComplete[int_] := 
 With[
  {string = "@#$kill me" <> ToString[int]}
  ,
  MakeExpression @@ {NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> string][[1]]][[
     1]], StandardForm}
  ]

getData[int_] := getDataHeldComplete[1][[1]];
```

Then evaluate evaluate in a new cell

```
getDataHeldComplete[1]
data=getData[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `TableForm` (you're already using this), `CellTags`, `NotebookLocate`, and `NotebookRead` to do this.

For your `Import` `"Output"` cell add a `CellTag` that will be your reference.

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[
  ImportString["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9", "CSV"] // TableForm,
  "Output",
  CellTags -> "Data1"]]
```

This can be re-executed at any time going forward without having to manually adjust. Of course you will use `Import` and not `ImportString`.

The cell can be located in the notebook with `NotebookLocate` and its contents read with `NotebookRead`.  When this is done you will see that the data is in a `GridBox` command.  `getCellTableFormData` finds the first occurrence of this and returns the first argument; which is the data array.

```
getCellTableFormData[tag_String] :=
 Module[{},
  NotebookLocate[tag];
  With[{cell = NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]},
   ToExpression@First@Extract[cell, FirstPosition[cell, GridBox[__]]]
   ]
  ]
```

Now `getCellTableFormData` can be used to assign a variable to the data collected from the tagged cell of `TableForm` output.

```
dat = getCellTableFormData["Data1"]
(* {{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}} *)
```

Even after you close and reopen the notebook the tagged cell is still there. So all that is need is to run the `getCellTtableFormData` definition (initialisation cell or a package) so that the variables can be set from the tagged cell data.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update**

Here is a version that does not change the selected cell to the tagged cell when the data is assigned to the variable. It is also a more concise.

```
getCellTableFormData2[tag_String] :=
 With[{cell = NotebookRead@First@Cells[CellTags -> tag]},
  ToExpression@First@Extract[cell, FirstPosition[cell, GridBox[__]]]
  ]
```

It does not use `NotebookLocate` which sets the selected cell to the tagged cell.

Comment: I appreciate the idea but the `NotebookLocate` method opens closed `CellGroup` containing the `Cell` with the data what is not appropriate. Both the `CellGroup` with initialization `Cell` and the `CellGroup`  with the data `Cell`s should remain closed in the course of initialization.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I've added another version that does not use `NotebookLocate`.  See update. I added a `2` onto the name so don't forget to change the call.  Maybe I should not have done that.

Comment: (+1) Yes, the `Cells` method works as desired. I think that `CellID` is even better than `CellTags` for my purpose because two `Cell`s with the same `CellID` are not allowed. The only problem is that the `Cells` function is absent in version 8 with which I still have to work because of insufficiently stable FrontEnds of versions 9 and 10.

Comment: Both your solutions extract numbers as `String`s. Instead of `First@Extract[...]` one can use `ToExpression[cell[[1]]]` for extraction numbers as numbers.

Comment: `CellID` is only guaranteed to be unique when created by the Wolfram System.  You are programming the notebook so you can be certain that the `CellTags` do not repeat for your data cells.  Does `CellID` persist on closing and reopening the notebook?  If they do then you might need to set negative number ids to be certain that the ids generated when executing the notebook don't overlap.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Good spot with the string issue.  I've added `ToExpression` to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you can write `data=` before your table and evaluate ? :

[image]