# How to generate an input cell?

Tags: cells

For example I have a block of code

```
Module[{}, a=1;b=2;...]
```

I want to have a function called `gencode`, so when I run `gencode`, it will generate an input cell which contains this block of code just like I type them by hand.

How to write this `gencode`?

Comment: `CellPrint` + `ExpressionCell[Defer@code, "Input"]`?

Comment: Hi, @MichaelE2. This works great. You could post it as an answer. What is more, I search the doc before, wish to find some tutorial page to deal with these cell things. But I can not find a suitable one. Could you recommend a link?

Comment: I don't really know a good reference. There's is this guide: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DocumentGeneration.html. I feel this is one my weaker areas of knowledge about *Mathematica*, even though I've generated homework assignments with such methods. Perhaps it's because there is not a good tutorial on it.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Output of code generated by CellPrint goes to the end of notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269955/280)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html) plus [`ExpressionCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionCell.html) are tools for generating cells.  They do not hold their arguments, so some control of evaluation is necessary (`Defer`). *[Update: In response to Szabolcs' comment about a default option value for `CellPrint` is `GeneratedCell -> True` (see also [this comment by John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/how-to-make-the-result-of-inputform-balance-the-bracket#comment403087_149583)), we should let options be passed.]*

```
ClearAll[gencode];
SetAttributes[gencode, HoldAll];
gencode[code_, opts : OptionsPattern[Cell]] := 
 CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Defer@code, "Input", opts];
```

Examples:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or following Szabolcs:

```
gencode[Module[{a, b}, a = 1; b = 2; a + b], GeneratedCell -> False]
```

Comment: +1, this is exactly what `Defer` is for. One note: the `Cell` will have `GeneratedCell -> True` . This means that Cell -> Delete All Output will delete it. It depends on the use case whether this is desired or not (I think usually it is not).  One can always set `GeneratedCell -> False`  in `ExpressionCell`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for such valuable comment. +1 : )

Comment: I don't know whether this should be a separate question but how do I appropriately control evaluation in the case where for example I have set the value `a=1` already and now want to generate `b=1` by using something of the form `gencode[b=a]`? That is I do want to fully evaluate both b and a but I don't want to evaluate the final set.

Comment: @Kvothe `With[{a = a}, gencode[b = a]]`? Or did I misunderstand what you wanted?

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks!

Comment: When I use this with the optional argument "InitializationCell", I get an initialization cell but it wraps the text unlike it usually does for this cell type. If I convert it "again" to an initialization cell it doesn't wrap. Is there anyway to create non-wrapping text programmatically? (I feel I just wasted my question on a stupid one  before and now I have a better one. Hope I didn't run out of your patience.)

Comment: @Kvothe In case it takes time, let's go to chat to work it out: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica

Comment: It is worth to mention here, that usage of `CellPrint` for producing `"Input"` cells is [discouraged](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149558/how-to-make-the-result-of-inputform-balance-the-bracket#comment403087_149583).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Note that Szabolcs raised this issue in the first comment, and I adjusted the definition of `gencode` to handle the last example, which addresses John Fultz's concern. John is obviously the leading expert on the FE, but I think the issue with `GeneratedCell -> True` is fairly clear and not subtle. -- Updated to highlight the point.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is more subtle than it should be. Try `Do[gencode[#, GeneratedCell -> False] &[i], {i, 3}]` - it prints in the reverse order! I don't know how to reproduce the behavior of `NotebookWrite` using `CellPrint`. Also, look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269963/280) example, which highlights why  `CellPrint` shouldn't be used in general for producing `"Input"` cells.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov `Do[gencode[#, GeneratedCell -> False] &[i], {i, 3}]` does just what the docs for `CellPrint` say: It inserts the cell just below the cell being evaluated. It's in the proper order: The last cell printed is just under the evaluated cell. I rather think this example goes beyond the use-case in the OP. If you want to insert multiple cells in specific places in a notebook, that might deserve a separate question. For instance, `CellPrint` on a list of cells does what you seem to want. But maybe you want help with `NotebookWrite`.

Comment: Here is a contradictory with the Docs: `CellPrint` with `GeneratedCell -> False` is a special case, while by default `Do[gencode[#] &[i], {i, 3}]` prints in the standard order (what contradicts the Docs, obviously). Also `CellPrint[Table[Cell[ToString@i, "Input", GeneratedCell -> False], {i, 3}]]` prints in the reverse order too, so it doesn't allow to reproduce the behavior of `NotebookWrite` (and also seems to be a bug).

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
NotebookWrite[
    EvaluationNotebook[]
  , Cell[ BoxData @ MakeBoxes @ Module[{a, b}, a = 1; b = 2; a + b], "Input"]
]
```

even this will do

```
NotebookWrite[
    EvaluationNotebook[]
  , MakeBoxes @ Module[{a, b}, a = 1; b = 2; a + b]
]
```

But only because "Input" is the default cell style.

Comment: Or equivalently using `Paste`: `Paste@Cell[BoxData@MakeBoxes@Module[{a, b}, a = 1; b = 2; a + b], "Input"]`.

Comment: Hi, @Kuba. Thank you so much for introducing fundamental `Boxes`, learned a lot : ) +1

Comment: Hi, @AlexeyPopkov I just found this could be as simple as `Paste@Defer@Module[{a, b}, a = 1; b = 2; a + b]`

Comment: @matheorem But this generates an `"Output"` cell, not an `"Input"` cell.