# How to generate Code cell including newlines

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I want to programmatically create a `"Code"` style cell with commands separated by `;` and a new line (from some list). Say for example I have a list `{set[a,1],set[b,2],...}` I would like to create the cell.

```
a=1;
b=2;
...
```

This can almost be done by following the answer to a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144900/45020), and replacing `"Input"` with `"Code"`. I find that `CompoundExpression@@{a,b,...}` does show as `a;b;...`, as I would like, but I don't know how to add the appropriate newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?:

```
format[l_List] := 
  ToBoxes@# /. {"set", "[", RowBox[{a_, ",", b_}], "]"} :> {a, "=", b, ";", "\n"} & /@ 
       l // RowBox // BoxData // Cell[#, "Code"] & // CellPrint;

format@{set[a, 1], set[b, 2], set[c, 2]}
```