# Can I generated an initialization cell using CellPrint?

Tags: cells, initialization

I want to do exactly what is done in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144896/how-to-generate-an-input-cell) post, except I would like the generated cell to be an initialization cell. That is, I'd like to have my code automatically generate an input cell with new code, ready to be evaluated (accomplished in liked post), **and** have this new cell be an initialization cell.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just add `InitializationCell -> True`.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, that worked! For some reason, this option isn't listed in Wolfram's documentation.