# Saving with many cells freezes in V13.1 and freezing time depends on the location of file

Tags: front-end, system-performance, version-13.1

**Update**

Ok, I got it with reproducible example. It turns out size is not the issue, number of cells is.

First, let us programmatically generates a lot cells according to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144896/4742). Basically, 3000 cells is enough at least on my computer.

```
Do[Paste@Cell[BoxData@MakeBoxes@0, "Input"], 3000]
```

will generate 3000 cells of just `0` then save it. Now test it according to my previous procedure.

Here is another gif show

[image]

---

**previous**

What I will show you in below gif is that

1. First, I was in a deep directory `C:/0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10` with a relatively large 25.7 MB test.nb contains a lot of stuffs. Open it and press Ctrl+S, take a look at the mouse cursor, we know it freezes for more than 10 seconds.
2. Then I copy exactly the same nb file to `C:/00` do the same thing, the freezing time reduces a lot, only 1 or 2 seconds.

[image]

Three problems:

1. The saving speed depends on directory structure does not make sense to me. Very weird. After all, it is not a too deep directory at all.
2. Even saving at `C:/00`, the freeze is also annoying. I still have 12.2 installed, and I do not encounter any freeze when saving in 12.2 no matter where this nb file is.
3. Any workaround? Or I have to fall back to 12.2 to work with some large nb file.

Comment: Does it happen (slowing) again when you move it back?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников You mean copy `C:/00` back to deep folder? Of course! the freeze is very robust :)

Comment: Have you reported it to the support? They at least should be informed, because the issue is important.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Nope yet... I think they could see it here : )

Comment: that happend to me few times, and one time while freezing MMA collaps and when restart again could not open the file due to errors..fortunately file was in Dropbox so I got old version otherwise would be a savere problem. Now working with MMA12.3 more save:-)

Comment: I could not reproduce it (Win10). I was very interested because I have an application the generates thousands of small cells.

Comment: @matheorem I have retracted my close vote. I can't test your problem now, and I see Gustavo can't reproduce your problem, however, I believe you have provided appropriate tools to at least attempt reproducing your issue, and therefore this should be an on-topic question now. I will delete my obsolete comments (including this one, later) and suggest other people do the same so we keep the discussion useful for future readers.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you very much

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Thank you so much for testing. That is weird. I am using win11 21H2. Have you tried even more cells?