# Can I store output data in the Notebook file? Specifically output from NDSolve[ ]

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting, core-language, output, storage

I am having some outputs from `NDSolve` of the form

```
{{x→InterpolatingFunction[…], y→InterpolatingFunction, … }}
```

and the evaluation of the respective commands can take a very long time.
So I would like the data to also be available once I close and reopen Mathematica and the notebook.

I know that I could manually export the raw data of each of these solutions into separate files, and then read it in again into the file.

But I find this a bit cumbersome, and it also ruins the nice feature of the output of `NDSolve` to be immediately ready for use in Plot routines, etc..

So my question is: Is there a way to just store these `NDSolve` outputs with the notebook, so that next time I open it up it is immediately available to me?

If not so. What would be the smartest and most efficient way to do instead?

Thanks a lot for your insights!

Comment: Look up [`Iconize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize)

Comment: @CarlWoll I tried that out now, and that is a great solution, thank you so much! There is one downside to it though: The saving and opening of the file now takes a much longer time than before. But I suppose the reasons for that are obvious, and one just cannot have one's cake and eat it at the same time. : )   Thanks again!

Comment: You could also investigate [`PersistentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentValue), [`PersistentObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentObject) and [`Once`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Once), as these functions won't store anything in the notebook.

Comment: Perhaps this related problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file) could help you.

Comment: [Check this out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/saving-data-inside-a-notebook-so-that-i-dont-have-to-run-it-again) also

Comment: Thanks again for all the answers! It seems like there are a multitude of options. I will play around with them and figure out what works best for my purposes. Thanks! : )