# Is there a way to embed a data set in a notebook?

Tags: import, notebooks

I have a data set (currently a table in a .csv file).  I would like to share this notebook with colleagues either as a notebook, or (even better) as a CDF document.  Is there a way to embed the data (on the order of a few megabytes) directly into the notebook?

Comment: David Reiss [Scientific Arts](http://www.scientificarts.com/index.html) had a blog some years ago in which he outlined this very thing. However, he seems to have taken this part of his website down.

Comment: @dwa I agree with belisarius, therefore I converted your post to a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate?: [(11891)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11891/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility would be to create a notebook cell containing the imported data in [`Compress`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compress.html)ed form:

```
testData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
Export["file.csv", testData];

f = Compress[Import["file.csv"]];
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"mydata", "=", ToBoxes[f], ";"}]], "Input"]]
```

Here, I created a test file and imported it. I store a compressed version in `f`. The [`NotebookWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookWrite.html) command inserts the string contained in `f` as a new cell in your current notebook. Now you can delete the previous lines and keep only the newly generated cell. It starts with `myData =`, and assigns the compressed file contents to that symbol. When you send a notebook containing this cell to someone else, they can then just evaluate that cell and get the data by doing [`Uncompress`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Uncompress.html) on the result. In the next two lines, I verify that this works by comparing to the original data:

```
reconstituted = Uncompress[mydata];
reconstituted == testData

(* ==> True *)
```

Comment: This does what I had asked originally.  Thank you very much for your time in answering.