# Get list value without displaying it on screen

Tags: core-language, variable-definitions, persistence

Having this code:

```
imagesData = 
  Module[{names = 
    Table[
      StringJoin[
        "D:\stuff\img_",
        ToString[n /. n -> If[nn <= 9, "0" <> ToString@nn, nn]],
        ".jpg"], 
      {nn, 0, 43, 1}]}, 
   Table[Import[names[[n]], "Data"], {n, 1, 44, 1}]];
```

I want to import some images. I don't want to import them every single time because it takes some time. Is it possible to assign the `imagesData` value (list of list of list I guess) to another variable so I dont have to import it every single time I open my notebook?

What I tried was to print it on screen, copy and paste the printed values so I can assign them to another variable. This methods is not an option, I guess, because the output generation time is so long. Is it possible to get what is in the variable without printing it on screen, so I will be able to assign its numerical value into another variable and therefore get rid of import time-consuming part?

Comment: first of all, have you tried `Export["imagesData.zip",{"imagesData.mx"->imagesData}]` which is the fastest and most compact way to reload MMA data from session to session. You bring it back in with `Import["imagesData.zip","imagesData.mx"]`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11891/attaching-a-file-to-a-notebook and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79561/131

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G No I haven't, however solutions provided by Yves Klett seems suitable for this task. Out of curiosity I will test your solution as well. Thanks for quick and precise answer!

Comment: Try using  `LocalSymbol` http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97498/making-large-calculation-results-persistent