# Saving an XMLObject imported inside a notebook

Tags: import

In a notebook, I import an XMLObject from a html file with this code line :

```
XMLData = 
  Import["Z:/XXX/XXX/XXX.mw", "XML"];
```

In order to have all the data in the notebook, is it possible to save the XMLObject inside th notebook so that for future uses, it is possible to not import the XMLObject.

The idea is to permit to send to somebody a notebook with all the data inside and not a notebook and a html file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This may be useful too: [attaching-a-file-to-a-notebook](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11891/57)

Answer (score 6):

You can store the data using tagging like so:

```
XMLData = Import["Z:/XXX/XXX/XXX.mw", "XML"];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules -> {"xmlData" -> XMLData}]
```

Then in future it can be recalled in the same notebook using the following line.  (The tagged data can be recalled even if the code above is deleted.)

```
XMLData = CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "xmlData"}]
```

Comment: XMLData = Import["Z:/XXX/XXX/XXX.mw", "XML"];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules -> {"xmlData" -> XMLData}]
XMLData = CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "xmlData"}]

I compile these 3 lines one time

After i try to suppress the first line linked to the import of my data XMLData = Import["Z:/XXX/XXX/XXX.mw", "XML"];, I can retrieve my data.

Do you have any suggestion so as to I can correct my process ?