# Exporting arrays for storage

Tags: export

I have a set of arrays I would like to output to some file `ArrayStorage.txt` s.t. these arrays could be read-in to a separate notebook on a separate kernel.  Is there an easy way to export a set of arrays?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to export a set of arrays" — the question seems to imply that existing methods are difficult. Have you tried looking in the help center? (press F1)

Comment: @rm-rf Exporting a single array looks pretty simple, but I'm asking about exporting and importing a list of arrays?

Comment: @FaintingWater A list of arrays is just a tensor of a higher rank. The question is: For which application do you want to export it?

Comment: @halirutan For Mathematica.  I would like a single file where I can reload all of my variables from another notebook after quitting the kernel?

Comment: can you be more specific? do you have a number of variables, say `a`, `b` and `c`, and would like to export them such that you can later re-import them all into the same variables? ie, run something and end up with the same array in each of `a`, `b` and `c` that you had earlier? or just one tensor of rank>2?

Comment: Then DumpSave is worth a look. You find it e.g. here in this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121/187

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save definitions, then `DumpSave` is one way to go:

```
a = RandomReal[1, 1000];
b = RandomInteger[10, 10000];
c = {blub, boing, ups};

DumpSave["tmp/out.mx", {a, b, c}];
```

Now you can quit the kernel or restart *Mathematica* and with

```
<< "tmp/out.mx"
```

`a`, `b` and `c` have their old values again.

One thing you should note is that files written by `DumpSave` can only be read on the same type of computer system on which they were written.

Comment: Always worth noting `DumpSave` is platform specific.

Comment: @kale I added this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way was suggested by David Bailey on MathGroup late last year (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/david$20bailey%7Csort:date/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/lf-EJeiqDwY/eEF29xJUFZwJ).

Briefly, as an alternative to MX files, try

```
 str=OpenWrite[file,BinaryFormat->True]; 
       BinaryWrite[str,magic,"TerminatedString"]; 
       BinaryWrite[str,Compress[{expr,version}],"TerminatedString"]; 
       Close[str];
```

to save, and

```
str=OpenRead[file,BinaryFormat->True]; 
    If[BinaryRead[str,"TerminatedString"]==magic, 
       expr=Uncompress[BinaryRead[str,"TerminatedString"]]; 
       ]; 
    Close[str];
```

to read.