# How to save all variables in the workspace into a file?

Tags: output-formatting, data, memory, save

I did some time consuming computation and obtained a lot of arrays and variables; however after restart the Mathematica Kernel, all these computational results disappeared.

How can I save all these workspace variables into some file, and then re-use them by loading the file next time when I restart Mathematica?

(In Matlab all the current workspace can be saved into an `*.mat` file by `save`, and re-used by `load`)

Comment: Have a look at [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html)... in fact, this looks like a duplicate of [Saving Mathematica kernel state?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121/131)

Comment: Thank you! That is the answer! Can I reuse the `.mx` file in C++ or any other programming language?

Comment: Quite probably not (easily)... but you could post another question on this, perhaps someone can answer with  authority.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Since there is already a good answer in the linked question (see my first comment), I will refrain from repeating that - please upvote the linked Q&A instead.

Comment: thank you very much! it is very nice of you!