# How to preserve In/Out tags like what they did in documentation files

Tags: front-end, formatting, stylesheet, persistence

Every evaluation generates a pair of In[n]/Out[n] signs tagged before actual input and output. Like the following:

[image]

If I save the file, close it and re-open it, that In[n]/Out[n] signs will disappear (as expected). Like the following:

[image]

However, A code example in documentation file will always have its In[n]/Out[n] signs no matter you have computed that piece of code or not. Like the following:

[image]

My question is: How to perserve the In[n]/Out[n] signs generated by computation even if I re-open the same file on a fresh kernel? Like what it looks like for documentation files.

Maybe it is necessary to use `DumpSave` like stated in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121/saving-mathematica-kernel-state) question?

Besides, how to access stylesheet of documentation files? If I can apply that style to my code notes would be great.

Comment: The documentation notebooks have `Savable -> False`, so you can edit but not save them. So all you need to do is to start with a clean kernel (`Quit`), evaluate the notebook, save and then set `Saveable` to `False`.

Comment: @rm-rf hrmm... answer?

Comment: @YvesKlett Can't use mma right now, so no dice. Please feel free to post it as an answer after verifying that it does work... I'm not sure I got the steps in the right order :)

Comment: @rm-rf Thank you for your advice. But I don't think it's a `Saveable` problem. (Or maybe you can enlighten me more precisely?) I have re-phrased my question. Hope it is clearer now?

Comment: @Naitree I was wrong then :) Mike's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `CellLabelAutoDelete->False`

You can do this programmatically:

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],CellLabelAutoDelete->False]`

or set it in your stylesheet.

Comment: Many thanks. A simple setting saved my day! :)