# Automatically restoring the state of a prior session

Tags: data, initialization

I have the following problem (I guess a very naive one): I work with some data and make a statistical analysis in *Mathematica*. I do it over several days and each time I open the file, I have to go through all previous lines of calculations, in order that all previously defined variables and data sets are uploaded into *Mathematica*'s memory.

My question is, does there exist a command so that each time I open the file, all defined previously variables are put into the working memory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely will be closed as duplicate, as pointed out by @Teake_Nutma, this has been answered already [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121/10397). In the meantime, the trick basically is:

To save:

```
DumpSave["state.mx", "Global`"]
```

To load:

```
Get["state.mx"]
```