# How to convert a list of names and values into a series of expressions

Tags: import

I had an Excel spreadsheet with a list of symbols names in the first column and a list of values in the second column. I imported it. Working with the resulting expression, I now have (in Mathematica) a list of names and a list of corresponding values.

```
names[[1 ;; 44]]
{"avogadro", "kgPerAmu", "gasConstant"...

values[[1 ;; 44]]
{6.02214*10^23, 1.66054*10^-27, 8.31446
```

What I want is a package with "assignement statements."

```
avogadro=6.23
boltzman=59
```

etc.
I have no idea how to convert a pair of lists into a series of expressions. In fact, I don't know what functions to look up in the documentation. How to get my constants into a package?

Comment: I think it is covered by the generic topic I've linked, let me know if you disagree with closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
MapThread[
 ToExpression["Set[" <> #1 <> "," <> ToString[#2] <> "]"] &,
 {names, values}
 ]
```

Comment: Or `ToExpression@StringTemplate["``=``"][##] &`

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
MapThread[Set, {Symbol /@ names, values}] (* or *)
Set @@@ Transpose[{Symbol /@ names, values}]
```

Comment: OK, MapThread[
 ToExpression["Set[" <> #1 <> "," <> ToString[#2] <> "]"] &, {namesd, 
  valuesd}] worked, but how do I make the symbols permanent? It is my experience that symbols in Mathematica just go away after a few days. It was a big deal creating the lists of names and symbols. I don't want to have to repeat it every day.

Comment: @GeneNaden Unless you save them they will go away, take a look at this topic and other topics linked there: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121/5478 As well as documentation for `Save/DumpSave` etc.

Comment: Yeah, I used Save command and it created a file with the lists in it, so that solved it.