Simple way to evaluate a cell in a separate kernel
I want to be able to evaluate a cell that takes a long time to evaluate while being able to evaluate other cells. I have looked at ParallelSubmit and ParallelEvaluate but neither seems to allow me to start and run a task in a separate kernel while leaving the main kernel free to do whatever (instead they have to actively "wait" for the results e.g. with WaitAll).
MMA does seem to have the capability because this answer gives a solution that seems to work. However, it feels very clumsy to work with the resulting palette. Moreover, the overwrite of the kernel creates errors afterwards when opening the Parallel Kernel Status:

Unable to communicate with closed link 
LinkObject[/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/14.0/Executables/wolfram 
-noinit -subkernel -wstp,362,17]
(...)
16 of 16 kernels failed to initialize.

And the new kernels do not show up in this status.
Despite these errors the palette does actually seem to work.
Is there a simpler way to just evaluate selected cells in a different kernel using either a key combination or an option accessible through right clicking or the evaluation menu bar?

The answer by Jason pointing out LocalSubmit almost completely solves this issue. However, the kernel used seems to not know of any of the definitions in the main kernel. Is there a way to pass along all definitions / the whole kernel state?
Example of the problem:
ClearAll[localSubmitDynamicDisplay]
SetAttributes[localSubmitDynamicDisplay,HoldAllComplete];
localSubmitDynamicDisplay[expr_]:=(res=Unique["res"];
    With[{insert=res},
        LocalSubmit[expr
        ,HandlerFunctions-><|"TaskFinished"->((insert=#EvaluationResult)&)|>
        ]
    ]; Print[res];Dynamic[res]);

var = {1, 2};
localSubmitDynamicDisplay[ValueQ[var]]


The following seems to work but is probably not the cleanest solution (using https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125/45020):
ClearAll[localSubmitDynamicDisplay]
SetAttributes[localSubmitDynamicDisplay,HoldAllComplete];
localSubmitDynamicDisplay[expr_]:=(res=Unique["res"];
    DumpSave["state.mx", "Global`"];
    With[{insert=res},
        LocalSubmit[Get["state.mx"];expr
        ,HandlerFunctions-><|"TaskFinished"->((insert=#EvaluationResult)&)|>
        ]
    ]; Print[res];Dynamic[res]);


"14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Have you seen LocalSubmit?

@DanielHuber, thanks! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Perhaps a stupid question but is there a way to make LocalSubmit create an output cell below it when it is done? I saw there is a way to save the output to a variable which I guess is good enough. I am just thinking of how I should handle retrieving results.

Regarding the edit: there are many discussions on this site, and examples in the documentation, about how to make sure that definitions from the main kernel are available in other kernels.  If those don't answer your question, please open another question about that subject.

@JasonB., any example answer/question? Or functions that have the same issue (to simplify looking for these)? The issue seems particular to LocalSubmit. Other similar functions I have used like ParellelEvaluate do share function definitions, so I haven't run into this problem before. LocalSubmit has no simple option to mimic the behavior of ParallelEvaluate?

You are right - it seems that SetSharedVariable and DistributeDefinitions do not work with LocalSubmit.  So that is a good question

As mentioned in the comments, LocalSubmit is the appropriate function for this.
Here is a minimal example showing how to (1) give a visible indication of when the job is done, and (2) assign the result to some variable in the main kernel:
status = "not finished";
LocalSubmit[
    Pause @ 5;
    Integrate[1 / (1 - Sqrt[x]) ^ 3, x],
    HandlerFunctions -> <|
        "TaskFinished" -> Function[
            status = "finished";
            res = #EvaluationResult
        ]
    |>
];
Dynamic @ status

You can do quite a lot using the HandlerFunctions.

Thanks! I had just written a similar function that dynamically displays the result SetAttributes[localSubmitDynamicDisplay,HoldAllComplete]; localSubmitDynamicDisplay[expr_]:=Module[{res},  With[{insert=res},   LocalSubmit[expr   ,HandlerFunctions-><|"TaskFinished"->((insert=#EvaluationResult)&)|>   ,HandlerFunctionsKeys->"EvaluationResult"   ]  ]; Dynamic[res]];
Edit: Hmm this seems to have a problem...

Put the line Dynamic @ status just after the line status = "not finished"; otherwise it deosn't work at the first evaluation of your code block.
